# username Logging on google analytics

Tags: web, google-analytics, tracking

All,

I have a site named xyz.com.
To  track the activities on this website i have used google analytics.
Ans to access xyz.com the user has to be logged in.
i.So my question is how do we track the usernames logged into the account.
ii.How to keep track of all the links that is clicked on the website.(Will google analytics listout all the link name when it is clicked.If so please indicate me the code.If not what other way can we track all the links that is clicked on the website.)

Thanks......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tracking outbound links:
http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55527

Custom variables would allow you to log whether a user is authenticated, and you could log their username itself ('though that could get clunky if you have lots of users):
http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingCustomVariables.html

Answer (score 0):

You can track which link is clicked by using the following function in the click event of the required link:

_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Category','Action','Optional Label']);